# Unable to load URL: This URL's domain is not included in the app's domain

Tags: php

I get the following error: Unable to load URL: This URL's domain is not included in the app's domain. In order to load this URL, all your apps' domains and subdomains must be added to the App domains field in your app settings. I can read from threads that previously this problem could be solved by disabling the "Use Strict Mode for Redirect URIs" however with the recent update from Facebook it's not possible to disable the function and I just cant make the facebook login work for our site.

Comment: You have to add the domain in your settings for the app at fecebook.

Comment: The domain already added in my app settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

The solution was to add the callback URI too (at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**YOUR-APP-ID**/fb-login/settings/ 
 -> Valid OAuth Redirect URIs), in my case, I had to add: http://*example.com*/auth/facebook/callback